# Adding common attributes to a Behave method

Tags: python, oop, python-behave

Using the great [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) framework, but having trouble with my lack of OOP skills.

Behave has an inbuilt context namespace where objects can be shared between test execution steps. After initializing my WebDriver session, I keep passing it between my steps using this `context` to hold everything. Functionality is fine, but as you can see below, it is anything but DRY.

How/where can I add these attributes to the `step_impl()` or `context` once only?

**environment.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def before_feature(context, scenario):
    """Initialize WebDriver instance"""

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args, desired_capabilities=dcap)

    """
    Do my login thing..
    """

    context.driver = driver
    context.wait = wait
    context.expected_conditions = expected_conditions
    context.xenv = env_data
```

**steps.py**

```
@given('that I have opened the blah page')
def step_impl(context):

    driver = context.driver
    wait = context.wait
    expected_conditions = context.expected_conditions
    xenv = context.xenv

    driver.get("http://domain.com")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("blah").click()
    wait.until(expected_conditions.title_contains("Blah page"))

@given(u'am on the yada subpage')
def step_impl(context):
    driver = context.driver
    wait = context.wait
    expected_conditions = context.expected_conditions
    xenv = context.xenv

    if driver.title is not "MySubPage/":
        driver.get("http://domain.MySubPage/")
        wait.until(expected_conditions.title_contains("Blah | SubPage"))

@given(u'that I have gone to another page')
def step_impl(context):
    driver = context.driver
    wait = context.wait
    expected_conditions = context.expected_conditions
    xenv = context.xenv

    driver.get("http://domain.com/MyOtherPahge/")
```

Comment: Is the question just how to avoid all of the unpacking from `context` in each `step_impl` function? I'd say you could cut out a bunch of it just by skipping the items you're not going to use later (e.g. `xenv` everywhere, `wait` and `expected_conditions` in the last version). Beyond that, you could skip some unpacking and just use the attributes of context directly, e.g. `context.driver.get(whatever)`. I know little about Behave, so I'm not sure if this is an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, to avoid all the unpacking *and* avoid duplication by calling `context.attribute.something` each time, neither of which feel very Pythonic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you can just skip this unpacking and use `context` attributes everywhere, like `context.driver.get("http://domain.com")`

If you don't like it and you really want to have local variables you can use tuple unpacking to make code little better:

```
import operator
def example_step(context):
    driver, xenv = operator.attrgetter('driver', 'xenv')(context)
```

You can factor out default list of attributes like that, but that makes the whole thing a little bit implicit:

```
import operator

def unpack(context, field_list=('driver', 'xenv')):
    return operator.attrgetter(*field_list)(context)

def example_step(context):
    driver, xenv = unpack(context)
```

If you still don't like that you can mangle with `globals()`. For example crate a function like that:

```
def unpack(context, loc, field_list):
    for field in field_list:
        loc[field]  = getattr(context, field, None)
```

And use it in your step:

```
def example_step(context):
    unpack(context, globals(), ('driver', 'xenv'))

    # now you can use driver and xenv local variables
    driver.get('http://domain.com')
```

This will reduce repetition in your code, but it is **very** implicit and could be dangerous. So it's not recommended to do it like that.

I'd just use tuple unpacking. It is simple and explicit so won't cause additional errors.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to use the tuple unpacking, but in this case received: `return [getattr(context, field) for field in context] TypeError: 'Context' object is not iterable`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the answer. It has to be `field_list`, not `context`

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Python you can't (usefully) assign to the return value of `locals()`. The dictionary returned by `locals()` is a copy of the local variables at the time you call it, but changes you make won't be reflected in the actual local namespace.

Comment: Your first `unpack` looks __a lot__ like `operator.itemgetter` ;-)

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, correct. You can use `globals()` instead of `locals()` but that would be even more implicit.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks, edited the answer. But it should be `operator.attrgetter`.

Comment: @AlexShkop -- Right, attrgetter.  Apparently it's time to leave SO for the night ...

Comment: Nice use of ``attrgetter``, didn’t know about that yet! Using ``globals()`` though is dangerous and very implicit, as you say—a later assignment to any of the unpacked variables (such as ``driver``) will bring interesting errors (unbound locals). One can still wrap the operator.attrgetter in one function to remove the duplication of the attribute names as strings to further minimize the repetition.

Comment: I'm interested to see what @JonasWielicki mean by wrapping the `attrgetter`. Though I don't want this to end up a game of code golf, minimal code is always nicer.

Comment: I guess @JonasWielicki meant to wrap `attrgetter` call in a function with some default parameter. So if parameter is not specified, it will use default list of attributes to extract. It will remove duplication of attribute names, but I don't like it because it will be easy to mismatch number of variables in LHS and RHS which will produce 'Too many values to unpack' error.

Comment: @AlexShkop right, I just realized that I was still in the mindset of having a constant set of attributes to unpack, forgetting that it would make sense to only unpack the attributes which are actually needed. In that case, wrapping makes no sense. (regarding your edit: setting the tuple as explict default does no harm here, tuples are immutable, so they’re safe as default arguments)

Comment: Thanks guys. I can realize the pros/cons between these solutions and have learnt a lot in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a decorator that 'unpacks' the context for you and passes the 'unpacked' values as arguments:

**environment.py**

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    context.spam = 'spam'

def after_feature(context, feature):
    del context.spam
```

**test.feature**

```
Scenario: Test global env
  Then spam should be "spam"
```

**step.py**

```
def add_context_attrs(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)  # wrap it neatly
    def wrapper(context, *args, **kwargs):  # accept arbitrary args/kwargs
        kwargs['spam'] = context.spam  # unpack 'spam' and add it to the kwargs
        return func(context, *args, **kwargs)  # call the wrapped function
    return wrapper

@step('spam should be "{val}"')
@add_context_attrs
def assert_spam(context, val, spam):
    assert spam == val
```

Comment: This works but I would rather not, since it hurts the readability and benifit is very limited.

Answer (score 1):

To stick to the DRY rule I usually use:
* Background stories: http://pythonhosted.org/behave/gherkin.html#background
* or Environmental controls: http://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html#environmental-controls

Comment: Here's an example feature file [twilio_handler.feature](https://github.com/kowalcj0/flaskrilio/blob/master/flaskrilio/features/twilio_handler.feature) with a Background story and here: [twilio_handler_steps.py](https://github.com/kowalcj0/flaskrilio/blob/master/flaskrilio/features/steps/twilio_handler_steps.py) is its steps implementation.